# remove specific endline breaks in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, fasta

I have a long fasta file and I need to format the lines. I tried many things but since I'm not much familiar python I couldn't solve exactly.

```
>seq1
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>seq2
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I want them to look like:

```
>seq1
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
>seq2
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I've tried this:

```
a_file = open("file.fasta", "r")
string_without_line_breaks = ""
for line in a_file:
    if line[0:1] == ">":
        continue
    else:
        stripped_line = line.rstrip()
        string_without_line_breaks += stripped_line
a_file.close()
print(string_without_line_breaks)
```

But the result not showing ">" lines and also merging all other lines. Hope you can help me about it. Thank you

Comment: You never added the line starting with `>` back into `string_without_line_breaks`, when you called `continue` which ends the execution of that iteration of the loop with that condition, moreover, you will need to figure out how to add back the final newline character that you need after having `rstrip()` it out.

Comment: FASTA files should not usually contain empty lines between the actual data; is your example correctly transcribed?

Comment: thank you @tripleee . Yes fasta file shouldn't contain empty lines. It's my mistake while posting this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common arrangement is to remove the newline, and then add it back when you see the next record.

```
# Use a context manager (with statement)
with open("file.fasta", "r") as a_file:
    # Keep track of whether we have written something without a newline
    written_lines = False
    for line in a_file:
        # Use standard .startswith()
        if line.startswith(">"):
            if written_lines:
                print()
                written_lines = False
            print(line, end='')
        else:
            print(line.rstrip('\n'), end='')
            written_lines = True
    if written_lines:
        print()
```

A common beginner bug is forgetting to add the final newline after falling off the end of the loop.

This simply prints one line at a time and doesn't return anything. Probably a better design would be to collect and `yield` one FASTA record (header + sequence) at a time, probably as an object. and have the caller decide what to do with it; but then, you probably want to use an existing library which does that - BioPython seems to be the go-to solution for bioinformatics.

Answer (score 2):

Since you’re working with FASTA data, another solution would be to use a [dedicated library](https://biopython.org/), in which case what you want is a one-liner:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

SeqIO.write(SeqIO.parse('file.fasta', 'fasta'), sys.stdout, 'fasta-2line')
```

Using the `'fasta-2line'` format description tells `SeqIO.write` to omit line breaks inside sequences.

Answer (score 1):

First the usual disclaimer: operate on files using a `with` block when at all possible. Otherwise they won't be closed on error.

Observe that you want to remove newlines on every line not starting with `>`, except the last one of every block. You can achieve the same effect by stripping the newline after every line that doesn't start with `>`, and prepend a newline to each line starting with `>` except the first.

```
out = sys.stdout
with open(..., 'r') as file:
    first = True
    hasline = False
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith('>'):
            if not first:
                out.write('\n')
            out.write(line)
            first = False
        else:
            out.write(line.rstrip())
            hasline = True
    if hasline:
        out.write('\n')
```

Printing as you go is much simpler than accumulating the strings in this case. Printing to a file using the `write` method is simpler than using `print` when you're just transcribing lines.

Comment: This loses the final newline

Comment: @tripleee. If that's a problem, I'll reinstate it momentarily

Comment: Windows victims seem to have a higher tolerance for missing final newlines. POSIX basically declares text files without a final newline to be invalid.

Comment: @tripleee. Fair enough. Fixed. Never had a problem with any Linux program beyond an occasional complaint from git

Answer (score -1):

I have edited some mistakes in your code.

```
a_file = open("file.fasta", "r")
string_without_line_breaks = ""
needed_lines = []
for line in a_file:
    if line.strip().startswith(">") or line.strip() == "":
        # If there was any lines appended before, commit it.
        if string_without_line_breaks != "":
            needed_lines.append(string_without_line_breaks)
            string_without_line_breaks = ""
        needed_lines.append(line)
        continue
    else:
        stripped_line = line.strip()
        string_without_line_breaks += stripped_line
a_file.close()
print("\n".join(needed_lines))
```

Comment: Consider elaborating on the mistakes and your solutions to them

Answer (score -3):

Please make sure to add the lines containing the right bracket (`>`) to your string.

```
a_file = open("file.fasta", "r")
string_without_line_breaks = ""
for line in a_file:
    if line[0:1] == ">":
        string_without_line_breaks += "\n" + line
        continue
    else:
        stripped_line = line.rstrip()
        string_without_line_breaks += stripped_line
a_file.close()
print(string_without_line_breaks)
```

By the way, you can turn this into a one liner:

```
import re

with open("file.fasta", 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

result = re.sub(r"^(?!>)(.*)$\n(?!>)", r"\1", data, flags=re.MULTILINE)

print(result)
```

The regex contains a negative lookahead to prevent trimming lines starting with `>`, and prevents trimming lines that are right before a `>`